# Display DataSet name

Tags: reporting-services

I have written a complex Stored Procedure that creates tables depending on the Parameter it recieves.

My SSRS report has 7 tables that need to be populated from this Stored procedure, so i have 7 DataSets, each executing the same stored procedure but with different Parameters so that it can populate each of the tables in my report.

My problem is, and even to me it sounds silly that I wouldnt know, I need to, on each of the 7 tables being populated by the SP, Show the DataSet name used for that particular table.

Does anyone know how to display the Dataset Name of the DataSet that each tablix on my report is using?

Comment: Data regions, such as tables, are bound to data sets statically (there is a static dataset property for a table). you could add static textbox with dataset name in it (outside of table, or in table header)

Comment: Hi, Thanks, sounds like it could be done. do you know the syntax to reference that value?

Comment: IIRC there is no way to get that. Just type the name as literal.

Comment: Output the parameter passed to the stored procedure in a column?

Comment: This question is a non-sequiter "I have an overly complex SP and I therefore want to use a dynamic method to label tables that are statically named"